# Looping through worksheets with PHPExcel

Tags: php, for-loop, phpexcel, worksheet

I'm using the PHPExcel library to read an Excel file and perform processing on it.  I want to loop through each worksheet.  I checked the documentation and all I could find was changing the active worksheet index or only loading specified worksheets.  How can I loop through all worksheets?

Thank you for any help.

Here is the documentation's looping example, for reference:

```
<?php
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("test.xlsx");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

echo '<table>' . "\n";
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
  echo '<tr>' . "\n";

  $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
  $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // This loops all cells,
                                                     // even if it is not set.
                                                     // By default, only cells
                                                     // that are set will be
                                                     // iterated.
  foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
  }

  echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using iterators. Did you look at the code example for iterators in the /Tests directory? If so, you might have seen reference to the WorksheetIterator

Alternatively, the getAllSheets() method of the PHPExcel object returns an array of worksheets, which allows you to use a foreach loop

Comment: Thank you very much!  I did find the iterator in the Test directory -- 28iterator.php.  getAllSheets() looks good, too.  Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

I think you can do this.  Increment the active sheet until there aren't any left, then do what you want with each one:

```
<?php

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("test.xlsx");

    $i = 0;
    while ($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i)){

        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        //now do whatever you want with the active sheet
        ...
        $i++;

    }

    ...

?>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Thanks for that answer.

Comment: you needs try ... catch construction, because last page throws exception

Comment: if($i <$objPHPExcel->getSheetCount()-1 ) $i++;
        else break;

add this in the end of the loop because will give you error finding non-existing last sheet

Answer (score 11):

Here's a useful function I use for iterating over sheets and returning an array of cell values for each with the sheet title as array key:

```
function getSheets($fileName) {
    try {
        $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($fileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);
        $sheets = [];
        foreach ($objPHPExcel->getAllSheets() as $sheet) {
            $sheets[$sheet->getTitle()] = $sheet->toArray();
        }
        return $sheets;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```