# Xlsx file, Read all spreadsheet in php

Tags: php

I am using simplexlsx to read xlsx sheet,

I have multiple tabs in my xlsx file, When I am trying to read data, its shows data only for first tab,

for better understanding i have attach print screen.

[image]

Comment: checkout PHP Excel https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617077/looping-through-worksheets-with-phpexcel, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081669/read-only-specific-sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

$this->load->library('simplexlsx');

$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( $file_path );

$data['csv_data'] = $xlsx->rows();

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you select something from an excel file it performs that action with the active sheet which is by default is the first one.

You need to change that to the required sheet 
Use the following code to do that

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($count); // Use no of the sheet you want to select -1 as count
```

Comment: Thanks Satyapal Sharma.